# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android

Estou com o AndroidManifest.xml acusando de erro.

Fora isso na linha 17 acusa de erro:

> Top level element is not completed

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="org.view.activityAcessar" />
    <activity android:name="org.view.activityMenu"></activity>

    <!-- Adicionado para reconhecer o Layout Primário -->
    <activity android:name="org.view.activityAcessar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

---

Modifiquei porém o erro continua.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity
    android:name="org.view.activityAcessar"
/>

<activity android:name="org.view.activityMenu">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O arquivo [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html?hl=pt-br) é o arquivo principal do projeto, onde  ficam todas as configurações. Ele obrigatoriamente deve ficar na pasta raiz do projeto, contendo todas as configurações necessárias para executar a aplicação, como o nome do pacote utilizado, o nome das classes de cada *activity* e várias outras configurações.

Verifique corretamente a estrutura do seu `AndroidManifest.xml`. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   package="br.com.exemplo.oimundo" 
   android:versionCode="1" 
   android:versionName="1.0">

   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity 
         android:name=".OiMundo" 
         android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Tente adaptar corretamente seu `AndroidManifest.xml` para que ele sem ocorrência de erros.

Leia mais sobre [estrutura do arquivo do manifesto na documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html?hl=pt-br#filestruct).

Sugiro que você leia um pouco também sobre [regras e convenções para nomenclatura de classes, pacotes, métodos, variáveis e constantes em Java](https://profsalu.wordpress.com/2014/11/25/regras-e-convencoes-para-nomenclatura-de-classes-pacotes-metodos-variaveis-e-constantes-em-java/)